# Specify link targets for index entries made with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, indexing

I have code for creating an index that refers readers to a page number and an example number. (The code is included in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165579/index-that-picks-up-on-example-numbers-not-page-numbers/239716#239716), reproduced below for convenience. I happen to be using `expex`, but it could just as well be an equation number, for example.) I would like to use `hyperref` to generate links to the specific example, rather than just the page. Is there a way to do this? I am using `xindy` as an index processor.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{expex,lipsum,index}
\newcommand{\PageExample}{\thepage-\the\excnt}
\newindex[PageExample]{my-index}{idx}{ind}{My Custom Index}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\ex \lipsum[1]\index[my-index]{First example} \xe

\ex \lipsum[2] \index[my-index]{Second example}\xe

\ex \lipsum[3] \index[my-index]{Third example}\xe

\ex \lipsum[4] \index[my-index]{Fourth example}\xe

\ex \lipsum[5] \index[my-index]{Fifth example}\xe

\ex \lipsum[6] \index[my-index]{Sixth example}\xe

\ex \lipsum[6] \index[my-index]{Seventh example}\xe

\printindex[my-index]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77656/8528)?

Comment: Thank you, that is just what I needed -- that page, and some thinking about macro expansion! I've added my solution in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution, based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77656/8528).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{expex,lipsum,index}
\newindex[PageExample]{my-index}{idx}{ind}{My Custom Index}
\usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref} % has to be after makeidx
\newcommand{\PageExample}{\thepage-\the\excnt}
\makeindex

\def\xindex#1#2{%
  \edef\doindexentry{\noexpand\index[#1]
    {#2|indexanchor{example:\the\excnt}}}%
    \doindexentry}

\def\indexanchor#1#2{\hyperlink{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\xindex{my-index}{First example}
\ex 
    \raisebox{\baselineskip}{\hypertarget{example:\the\excnt}{}}\ignorespaces%
    \lipsum[1] 
\xe

% now make the code prettier:
\def\iex#1{%
    \xindex{my-index}{#1}%
    \ex %
    \raisebox{\baselineskip}{\hypertarget{example:\the\excnt}{}}\ignorespaces}

\iex{Second example} \lipsum[2] \xe

\iex{Third example} \lipsum[3] \xe

\iex{Fourth example} \lipsum[4] \xe

\iex{Fifth example} \lipsum[5] \xe

\iex{Sixth example} \lipsum[6] \xe

\iex{Seventh example} \lipsum[7] \xe

\printindex[my-index]
\end{document}
```

There are two "tricks" to it. The first is that the a macro that creates a hyperlink is passed to `\index` as if it were a formatting command (e.g., `\index{Joe|indexanchor}` instead of `\index{Joe|textit}`).

The second trick is to use `\edef` to expand all of the needed macros before then calling it to call the `\index` macro. If `\xindex` had a call to `\index` outside of `\edef`, then it would write something like this to the .idx file: `\indexentry {First example|indexanchor{example: \the \excnt}}{1-1}`.