# Xindy and custom Hyperref index entries

Tags: xindy

My goal is to have index entries that provide hyperlinks to specific examples on a page, using `xindy`. This follows from an [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240091/specify-link-targets-for-index-entries-made-with-hyperref/240153); that question has code that works with `makeindex`. It creates an `.idx` file with entries like this:

```
\indexentry {First example|indexanchor{example:2}}{1(2)}
\indexentry {Second example|indexanchor{example:3}}{1(3)}
\indexentry {Third example|indexanchor{example:4}}{1(4)}
```

Running such an `.idx` file through `xindy` produces errors like this, as `xindy` interprets the input as cross-references:

```
WARNING: unknown cross-reference-class `indexanchor'! (ignored)
```

How can `xindy` process these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I came up with is to teach `xindy` to recognize hyperlink commands as types of page references. (The code that follows doesn't able page range references, but I simply didn't include that because it's irrelevant to my application.)

The code generates an `.idx` file like this, with the hyperlink command included as part of the page reference. (`\indexanchor` is defined below; the `"` marks are just escapes for `{`.

```
\indexentry{First example}{\indexanchor{example:1"}{1(1)"}}
\indexentry{Second example}{\indexanchor{example:2"}{1(2)"}}
\indexentry{Third example}{\indexanchor{example:3"}{1(3)"}}
```

`xindy` just needs to be told what these page ranges look like. This is `xindy-hyperref.xdy`:

```
(define-location-class "page-example-hyperref" ( :sep "\indexanchor{example:" "arabic-numbers" :sep "}{" "arabic-numbers" :sep "(" "arabic-numbers" :sep ")}" ))
```

To produce the `.idx` in the proper format, I needed to create my own output structure. (I would be interested if anyone had a more elegant way to redefine a macro from an indexing package. When it came to it I was surprised at how simple it was to write my own indexing code.) `xindy-hyperref.tex:`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{expex,hyperref,lipsum}
% open the index file
\newwrite\outputstream
\immediate\openout\outputstream=xindy-hyperref.idx
% Index references like 2(3)
\newcommand{\PageExample}{\thepage (\the\excnt)}
% Write the index entries to a file
\def\xindex#1#2#3{%
    \immediate\write#3{\string\indexentry {#2}{\string\indexanchor{example:\the\excnt"}{\PageExample"}}}
    }
\def\indexanchor#1#2{\hyperlink{#1}{#2}}
% clean output
\def\iex#1{%
    \xindex{my-index}{#1}{\outputstream}%
    \ex %
    \raisebox{\baselineskip}{\hypertarget{example:\the\excnt}{}}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\iex{First example} \lipsum[1] \xe

\iex{Second example} \lipsum[2] \xe

\iex{Third example} \lipsum[3] \xe

\iex{Fourth example} \lipsum[4] \xe

\iex{Fifth example} \lipsum[5] \xe

\iex{Sixth example} \lipsum[6] \xe

\iex{Seventh example} \lipsum[7] \xe

\InputIfFileExists{xindy-hyperref.ind}{}{}

\end{document}
```

To compile the example:

```
xelatex xindy-hyperref.tex
texindy -L english xindy-hyperref.idx -o xindy-hyperref.ind -M xindy-hyperref
xelatex xindy-hyperref.tex
```